# Code command in terminal doesn't open in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, terminal

when I open my project in intellij an I want to write a new java file with the terminal with the Code command it opens the vscode instead of opening the file in intellij.
I tried to find a solution with nothing in return.

I hope you can help me find a solution.

Comment: It is not clear what you are doing. Please provide detailed steps to reproduction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`code`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line) command is the command-line interface to Visual Studio Code. It can only open that application.

IntelliJ IDEA offers its own way to [use it from the command line](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-the-ide-features-from-command-line.html).

The instructions for installing the command line tool vary depending on the operating system and the way the application was installed.

You can use it in a similar way:

```
idea MyFile.java
```